# Is there anyway I can optimize this code to much shorter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filter, contains

Is there anyway I can optimize this code into shorter? 
MakeList, TrimList and etc are List type.
and Vehicle are models. 
My problem is code is very long. I have 20 property in model.

---

```
if (MakeList?.Any() == true)
{
    bidVehicles = bidVehicles.Where(b => MakeList.Contains(b.Vehicle.Make));
}
if (TrimList?.Any() == true)
{
    bidVehicles = bidVehicles.Where(b => TrimList.Contains(b.Vehicle.Trim));
}
if (ModelList?.Any() == true)
{
    bidVehicles = bidVehicles.Where(b => ModelList.Contains(b.Vehicle.Model));
}
if (StockNoList?.Any() == true)
{
    bidVehicles = bidVehicles.Where(b => StockNoList.Contains(b.Vehicle.StockNo));
}
if (BodyStyleList?.Any() == true)
{
    bidVehicles = bidVehicles.Where(b => BodyStyleList.Contains(b.Vehicle.Body));
}
if (ExtColorList?.Any() == true)
{
    bidVehicles = bidVehicles.Where(b => ExtColorList.Contains(b.Vehicle.Exterior));
}

return bidVehicles;
```

Comment: And what are `MakeList, TrimList` etc?

Comment: @SeM - They are List<string> sir.

Comment: Shorted code is not always easier to understand, you can remove the comparison to ==true, other than that I would be looking more for refactoring the code, you seem to be building a dynamic where clause, look to see if you can generate that separately.

Comment: @peeyushsingh - Yes I'm building dynamic where clause. If I refactor it too many parameters will be attach.

Comment: The thing is, that you can technically shorten this part of the code, by writing some code, which may or may not be longer than this.

Comment: Also, _Optimal_ and _Short_ not necessarily are the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For LINQ to Objects:

```
public static class FilterExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TItem> ApplyFilter<TProp, TItem>(this IEnumerable<TItem> list, List<TProp> filter, Func<TItem, TProp> prop)
    {
        if (filter == null || filter.Count == 0)
        {
            return list;
        }

        return list.Where(x => filter.Contains(prop.Invoke(x)));
    }
}

...

var filtered = bidVehicles
    .ApplyFilter(MakeList, x => x.Vehicle.Make)
    .ApplyFilter(TrimList, x => x.Vehicle.Trim).ToList();
```

If you use EF (means `bidVehicles` is `IQueryable`) you have to write expression for each property because you need full predicate `Expression<Func<BidVehicle, bool>>` not just `Func<BidVehicle, TProp>`.

Comment: `if (filter?.Count == 0)`

Comment: @AnthonyQuartz I made method generic to support filtering by different types.

Comment: I have an error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Invoke(BidVehicle)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @AnthonyQuartz How do you call `ApplyFilter`?

Comment: bidVehicles = bidVehicles.ApplyFilter(Make, x => x.Vehicle.Make);

I have IQueryable.

Comment: @AnthonyQuartz It's an important note, let me think.

Comment: @mtkachenko just change `IEnumerable<BidVehicle>` to `IQueryable<BidVehicle>`

Comment: @Magnus I suppose EF can't translate delegate into sql, it requires predicate expression.

Comment: @mtkachenko yeh,, I suppose it should be: `Expression<Func<BidVehicle, TProp>>`

Comment: Sir @mtkachenko I already solve. Thank you for this solution. I modify your code a bit and it works now. I add .AsExpandable() before .Where.

Comment: "*For LINQ to Entities*"? I guess you mean LINQ to **Objects**, because to *Entities* definitely means EF, hence `IQueryable`.